# Expected End Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macros in VBA to select something from a drop down and then select the corresponding sheet. I keep getting the compile error expected end sub.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
Public Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = Range("Select.Type").Address Then
        Select Case target.Value
            Case "M/M/1/GD/INF/INF"
                Sheets("M-M-1-GD-INF-INF").Select
            Case "M/M/1/GD/C/INF"
                Sheets("M-M-1-GD-C-INF").Select
            Case "M/M/S/GD/INF/INF"
                Sheets("M-M-S-GD-INF-INF").Select
            Case "M/M/R/GD/K/K"
                Sheets("M-M-R-GD-K-K").Select
            Case "Closed Queuing Network"
                Sheets("CQN").Select
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `End Sub` for `Sub Macro3`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. But in line 1 you wrote:

```
`Sub Macro3()
```

To change into a comment please use the sign:

```
'
```

and not the sign

```
´
```

So it should be:

```
'Sub Macro3()
```

But why you don't delete `Sub Macro3(). It's not needed. Your procedure starts with:

```
Public Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
```

I don't know, if you know to put your procedure not in a module. You need to put it into the code from the sheet, where your dropdown-list is. There you don't need to run the macro. It runs permanently by itself, if a cell in this sheet is changed. (Double click on the sheet on the left side in the visual basic editor and include there your code)

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a sub which is named macro3. This sub has a missing end sub statement.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
End Sub
'
Public Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Address = Range("Select.Type").Address Then
        Select Case target.Value
            Case "M/M/1/GD/INF/INF"
                Sheets("M-M-1-GD-INF-INF").Select
            Case "M/M/1/GD/C/INF"
                Sheets("M-M-1-GD-C-INF").Select
            Case "M/M/S/GD/INF/INF"
                Sheets("M-M-S-GD-INF-INF").Select
            Case "M/M/R/GD/K/K"
                Sheets("M-M-R-GD-K-K").Select
            Case "Closed Queuing Network"
                Sheets("CQN").Select
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```